.Net Nuget package for 4.8 working in my 8.0 app until Deployment
I have a new application I'm writing (a web service using .Net 8.0) that uses a vendor's nuget package that targets .Net 4.8.
When I use it in my application, everything is fine.  No issues.  However, when I create my yml in Azure DevOps to do the build and deploy, I specify the correct feed in the nuget.config and it picks it up, but the nuget restore command fails because it knows it's not a compatible framework.
Is there a way to get around this?  I know it works, and I'm only targeting Windows, so I shouldn't have to worry.
.csproj File:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ObfuscatedPackageName" Version="24.2.6.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Models\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

nuget Package Details:


.NET 8 is .NET Core 8. You can't use a .NET Framework package in a .NET Core application. Only packages that target .NET Standard 2.0 can be used by both runtimes.

Then I'm confused.  Why is it that I can pull this nuget package fine in my .Net 8.0 application and use it...and it doesn't complain or balk at it?  The application runs just fine.

We can't guess unless you specify which package is used. Perhaps you're directly referencing a local DLL. Perhaps your project targets both runtimes and you debug with .NET Framework 4.8 instead of .NET 8. At the very least post your csproj file. The Manage Dependencies dialog itself wouldn't allow you to install a .NET Framework package in a .NET Core application

Updated to show my proj file and the nuget details.  Again, no errors and no warnings in Visual Studio.  I am NOT targeting 4.8, unless Visual Studio is doing some weird thing in the background where it targets it itself.

It doesn't complain until something breaks right under your node, which was unfortunately a change made in .NET Core 2.x to improve compatibility experience for developers. But if you fully rely on VS to show you all the warnings/errors, you should be aware of the limitation.


What's the result if you run dotnet restore or nuget.exe restore to restore packages from Azure Artifact? 2. What's the error you get in your pipeline. It's better to share the completed error message.

